# Поменять местами переменные без использования третьей переменной в Си

Tags: c

Если мне не изменяет память был способ одной строкой поменять местами значения переменных в Си с помощью ф-ции в одном из стандартных заголовочных файлах. Не напомните (если я ничего не путаю)? Спс.

Comment: В стандартном не помню, WINAPI - InterlockedExchange

Comment: Может cpp? [std::swap](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: `#define XORSWAP(a, b)   ((&(a) == &(b)) ? (a) : ((a)^=(b),(b)^=(a),(a)^=(b)))`

Comment: нет, си, а не cpp

Comment: [`a^=b^=a^=b`](https://ideone.com/cBzi3D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете самостоятельно написать такую функцию:

```
// значения a и b надо поменять местами

int a = 3;
int b = 5;

a = a + b; // a = 8
b = b - a; // b = -3
b = -b;    // b = 3
a = a - b; // a = 5
```

Соответственно, последние четыре строчки Вы выносите в отдельную функцию или как там Вам требуется. Обращаю внимание, этот способ применим для переменных числовых типов.

Answer (score 1):

Может так : a=a+b-(b=a); Проверить, к сожалению, не могу.

Comment: На java работает.